# When browsing for files from iCloud Drive in Safari, some app folders are disabled

Tags: ios, safari, icloud, icloud-drive

Can someone explain why some app folders are disabled in iCloud Drive when browsing for files from Safari?  These files are available at iCloud.com, but the folders for some apps (including mine, Automator shown below) are disabled inside of Safari.

I added the following to make my app's folder public, but it still shows as disabled in Safari:

```
<key>NSUbiquitousContainers</key>
    <dict>
        <key>iCloud.com.example.MyApp</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSUbiquitousContainerIsDocumentScopePublic</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSUbiquitousContainerSupportedFolderLevels</key>
            <string>Any</string>
            <key>NSUbiquitousContainerName</key>
            <string>MyApp</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This was resolved by adding an entry for `UTExportedTypeDeclarations` to the Info.plist file